# Игнорирование символов строки

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

Как в python вывести содержимое txt файла, игнорируя некоторые элементы(например первый и последний)?.Нужно именно не перезаписать, а лишь считать игнорируя определенные элементы.

Comment: Игнорируя элементы чего?

Comment: ну например есть текстовой файл, там 5 строк и нужно игнорировать 1ый символ этого документа и последний

Comment: Игнорировать первый символ первой строки или каждой строки?

Comment: 1ый символ первой строки и последний символ последней строки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
n= line[1:-1].rstrip()
```

со 2 до предпаследнего

строка начинается с 0 символа

```
например 'hello word'
[1:-1] = 'ell wor'
[2:-3] = 'llo w'
```

1ый символ первой строки и последний символ последней строки

```
s1 = 'hello word'
s2 = 'hello word3'
s3 = 'hello word4'
s = s1+s2+s3
s[1:-1] = 'ello wordhello word3hello word'
```

если это все в файле то:

```
myfile=open("myfile.txt")
n = ''
for line in myfile:
     n += line.rstrip()
print(n[1:-1])
```

Comment: 1ый символ первой строки и последний символ последней строки

Comment: @Jevgewa, ну так загони весь файл в одну строку.

Comment: NameError: name 'n' is not defined

Comment: при копмиляции вашего последнего представленного кода

Comment: добавьте переменную n=''